# Быстрый поиск по строке C++

Tags: c++

Есть код поиска подстроки в строке, вроде бы достаточно простой и быстрый. Однако, perf говорит, что функция поиска работает 16% всего времени.

Реализация rtms(): https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/blob/master/msvcore/crossplatform/rts.cpp#L32

Вся нагрузка идет на строку "if(*line==*fr){"

```
 :                        if(*line==*fr){                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
7,64 :          4d5348:       mov    -0x40(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
8,12 :          4d534c:       mov    (%rax),%rax                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
0,04 :          4d534f:       movzbl (%rax),%edx                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
9,11 :          4d5352:       mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
7,66 :          4d5356:       movzbl (%rax),%eax
```

Есть более быстрый алгоритм поиска?

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически, более быстрым алгоритмом поиска может быть префикс-функция.